# Elixir: (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression

Tags: math, elixir

I have a simple calculation:

```
Enum.reduce(1..5, 0, &:math.pow/2)
```

But I get this error:

```
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    (stdlib) :math.pow(5, 262144.0)
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1478: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/range.ex:80: Enumerable.Range.reduce/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1477: Enum.reduce/3
```

Is there a limitation in Elixir for arithmetic calculations?

Comment: Did you really mean to reduce `1..199` with `pow`? That's going to be a really huge number. Even `1..5` will produce a number with around 180,000 digits ([Source](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5+%5E+262144.0)).

Comment: I am learning Elixir and I am introducing myself with it's limits.  I knew it's a huge number. But I actually need to understand the limits.  And BTW,  whats wrong with 180k digits? Its just a big number.

Comment: That's just `1..5`. `1..10` will produce [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E9%5E8%5E7%5E6%5E5%5E4%5E3%5E2%5E1) and you're trying to run `1..199`.

Comment: It's just an example.  I decreased the number in question.  and that's not the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to calculate `5^262144` - it's such a huge number erlang bails out. Such number can't even be represented by floating point numbers - the maximal float is about `1.7e308`

Comment: So i guess I have to ask, how to calculate 5^262144 in Erlang? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38533313/895659)

Comment: why it is not possible, I thought erlang has arbitrary length numbers (just like python, and I was able to do `5**262144` there and got answer)

Comment: @krzyk Not possible and you were able to get answer?

Comment: While erlang has arbitrary-size integers, the `:math` module operates on floats, and can handle only values representable by floating point numbers. This module is effectively a thin wrapper around `math.h` from C. I don't believe The standard library has a module to do arbitrary integer exponentiation.