# How to calculate 5^262144 in Erlang

Tags: math, erlang, elixir, bigdata

Based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38533313/895659) question, I realized that calculating such numbers seems not possible in regular ways.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible, but you need an algorithm that is a bit more clever than the naive solution. If you write the naive power function, you do something along the lines of:

```
pow(_, 0) -> 1;
pow(A, 1) -> A;
pow(A, N) -> A * pow(A, N-1).
```

which just unrolls the power function. But the problem is that in your case, that will be 262144 multiplications, on increasingly larger numbers. The trick is a pretty simple insight: if you divide N by 2, and square A, you almost have the right answer, except if N is odd. So if we add a fixing term for the odd case, we obtain:

```
-module(z).

-compile(export_all).

pow(_, 0) -> 1;
pow(A, 1) -> A;
pow(A, N) ->
    B = pow(A, N div 2),
    B * B * (case N rem 2 of 0 -> 1; 1 -> A end).
```

This completes almost instantly on my machine:

```
2> element(1, timer:tc(fun() -> z:pow(5, 262144) end)).
85568
```

of course, if doing many operations, 85ms is hardly acceptable. But computing this is actually rather fast.

(if you want more information, take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring )

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested how compute power using same algorithm as in [I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25083/i-give-crap-answers)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38534076/49197) but in tail recursive code, there it is:

```
power(X, 0) when is_integer(X) -> 1;
power(X, Y) when is_integer(X), is_integer(Y), Y > 0 ->
    Bits = bits(Y, []),
    power(X, Bits, X).

power(_, [], Acc) -> Acc;
power(X, [0|Bits], Acc) -> power(X, Bits, Acc*Acc);
power(X, [1|Bits], Acc) -> power(X, Bits, Acc*Acc*X).

bits(1, Acc) -> Acc;
bits(Y, Acc) ->
    bits(Y div 2, [Y rem 2 | Acc]).
```

Answer (score 0):

It simple since Erlang uses arbitrary-precision for integers(big numbers) you can define own function pow for integer, for example:

```
-module(test).
-export([int_pow/2]).

int_pow(N,M)->int_pow(N,M,1).

int_pow(_,0,R) -> R;
int_pow(N,M,R) -> int_pow(N,M-1,R*N).
```

Note, I did not check the arguments and showed the implementation for your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
defmodule Pow do
  def powa(x, n), do: powa(x, n, 1) 
  def powa(_, 0, acc), do: acc
  def powa(x, n, acc), do: powa(x, n-1, acc * x)
end
```

Apparently

```
Pow.powa(5, 262144) |> to_string |> String.length
```

yields

```
183231
```

long number that you were curious about.